# Issue with GROUP_CONCAT AND ORDER BY FIELD in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, group-concat

I'm having some issues with a query. I would like to ORDER a query BY a number of id's. Here is my query:

**This query doesn't return the result as I would like :(**

```
SELECT *
FROM question q
INNER JOIN answer a ON a.question_id = q.question_id
WHERE q.lesson_id = 1
AND q.question_id IN (
    SELECT e.question_id
    FROM exame e
    WHERE e.inscription_id = 1
    AND e.lesson_id = 1
    AND e.attempt = 1
    ORDER BY e.question_id
) /*this subquery returns (10,2,1,8,3,12,4,11,14,7)*/
ORDER BY FIELD(q.question_id,(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ee.question_id ORDER BY ee.order_of_appearance SEPARATOR ',') AS final_order
    FROM exame ee
    WHERE ee.inscription_id = 1
    AND ee.lesson_id = 1
    AND ee.attempt = 1)
) /*this subquery returns (10,2,1,8,3,12,4,11,14,7)*/
```

As you can see, the two subqueries return the same result (10,2,1,8,3,12,4,11,14,7). As you know, the difference between them is that the first one returns a resultset and the second one only a field with all the id's concatenated.

**Issue #1:** If I copy the first subquery and write it in the place where the second one is located, I get this error:

> 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

So I've created the second subquery (with the GROUP_CONCAT function), but the result isn't what I was expecting. The result is ordered by "question_id" and I want that it has ordered by "order_of_appearance" field.

**Issue #2:** If I write the subquery inside the ORDER BY clause, I don't get the result ordered by "order_of_appearance" field, but if I delete the subquery and I manually write the array of id's, the result is ordered by "order_of_appearance"!! WHY???

**This query returns the result as I would like!! :)**

```
SELECT *
FROM question q
INNER JOIN answer a ON a.question_id = q.question_id
WHERE q.lesson_id = 1
AND q.question_id IN (
    SELECT e.question_id
    FROM exame e
    WHERE e.inscription_id = 1
    AND e.lesson_id = 1
    AND e.attempt = 1
    ORDER BY e.question_id
)
ORDER BY FIELD(q.question_id,10,2,1,8,3,12,4,11,14,7)
```

**Final question:** Is it possible to achieve what I want without having to write manually the array of id's? I need to do it dinamically.

Thanks in advance! (I hope you understand my english!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to use `FIND_IN_SET()` instead of `FIELD()`:

From the reference manual:

> [`FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field)
>
> **Returns the index (position) of `str` in the `str1`, `str2`, `str3`, ... list. Returns 0 if str is not found.**
>
> If all arguments to `FIELD()` are strings, all arguments are compared as strings. If all arguments are numbers, they are compared as numbers. Otherwise, the arguments are compared as double.
>
> If `str` is `NULL`, the return value is 0 because `NULL` fails equality comparison with any value. `FIELD()` is the complement of `ELT()`.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT FIELD('ej', 'Hej', 'ej', 'Heja', 'hej', 'foo');
>     -> 2
>
> mysql> SELECT FIELD('fo', 'Hej', 'ej', 'Heja', 'hej', 'foo');
>     -> 0
> ```

---

> [`FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)
>
> **Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings.** A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. If the first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type `SET`, the `FIND_IN_SET()` function is optimized to use bit arithmetic. Returns 0 if `str` is not in `strlist` or if `strlist` is the empty string. Returns `NULL` if either argument is `NULL`. *This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character*.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
>     -> 2
> ```

Comment: Gracias @Barranka!! It's woked!! I've used FIND_IN_SET() and suddenty I've got my desired result!! Thank you so much!! Saludos desde España!

Comment: @user3800667 Happy to help. Por cierto, también hay una comunidad de StackOverflow en español: http://es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: gracias @Barranka! Le echaré un ojo!